# Difference between instance and singleton in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, instance

I have a basic question that can help new unity guys to learn faster. As you know that in unity we both use singleton and instance of a class. I have realised a thing that and I want to be sure about what I am thinking. Can you help me to be sure?

I use instance in some situations like this;

If I have a scene and I want to use instance as a layer to transfer some data between scripts. I create an empty game object and assign this code it as a component;

```
public class GameplayController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameplayController instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        MakeInstance();
    }

    void MakeInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if(instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I use singleton in some situations like this;

If I have a scene and I want to use singleton pattern as a layer to transfer some data between all scenes. I create an empty game object and assign this code it as a component;

```
public class GameplayController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameplayController instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        MakeSingleton();

    void MakeSingleton()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else if(instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I wanted to be sure If I am on the right way or not? It worked until now, but will be there a problem in most advanced situations in the future?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern) post helps you. I think you should go for singleton design pattern for more reliable and exact solution to your game :)

Comment: well the difference between `instance` and `singleton` is actually: `Singleton` is the name of a design pattern. `Instance` is an object of the type of a class. So yes your `instance` variable in this case implements the `singleton` functionality. You could however simply use `if(!instance) { instance = this; }` and skip the second condition and simply use `else{ Destroy(gameObject); }`. If you don't need that instance `public` than make it `private` .. using the handy sideeffect of having that instance `public static` **will** cause troubles in the future because of unvisible dependencies ;)

Comment: Just a quick answer. Instance is giving a class an actual or a usable value, i.e: Class is GameCharacter, then an instance can be Mario, Luigi, Bowser. Singleton, is making sure that a class will only have one instance throughout its lifetime, so given the previous example if you make an GameCharacter instance (Mario), you cannot make Luigi, Bowser. It is still possible to make them but it would be contradicting the purpose of Singleton.

Comment: The only difference in your two code samples there (ignoring the typo-missed `}`) is the call to `DontDestroyOnLoad`. Using or not using doesn't change that you have a singleton, just that your instance (and therefor the d data it hold) lives across scene load boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, that's the basic way to create a singleton in Unity.

When you speak of Instance vs Singleton I'm getting some vibes that you may not understand the concept: The idea with Singleton is that there will only be ONE (single) instance of the object.

So you have a static property; the static modifier on a class makes it non-instansiable with the `new` keyword. When you add it to a property (like you've done) it means that you can access it from anywhere, without instansiating the containing class.

```
GameplayController.instance
```

In your MakeInstance() you verify that the instance isn't already assigned to an instance, and then set it to this instance.

To further follow the Singleton pattern you probably want to make sure your object isn't destroyed when you load a new scene:

```
if (instance == null)
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    instance = this;
}
```

There shouldn't be any problems in the future; the Singleton pattern is a bad pattern however, but it has its usefulness in prototyping; it's simple.

Issues you may experience is that your code will have dependencies to your Singleton classes which will cause errors if you've forgotten to add the class to the Scene, or if you have an earlier scene where you instansiate these classes you have to start that Scene first when debugging, etc.

Personally I use a Singleton class to extend to assure same functionality across all Singletons and less bloat in every Singleton class etc:

```
using UnityEngine;
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T _instance;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (applicationIsQuitting)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("[Singleton] Instance '" + typeof(T) +
                    "' already destroyed on application quit." +
                    " Won't create again - returning null.");
                return null;
            }

            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    var instances = FindObjectsOfType<T>();
                    if (instances.Length > 1)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("[Singleton] Something went really wrong " +
                            ", there are too many Singletons; deleting them: ");
                        for (int i = 1; i < instances.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Debug.LogError("Deleting " + instances[i].gameObject.name);
                            Destroy(instances[i].gameObject);
                        }
                        _instance = FindObjectOfType<T>();
                        return _instance;
                    }

                    if (instances.Length > 0)
                        _instance = instances[0];

                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        GameObject singleton = new GameObject();
                        _instance = singleton.AddComponent<T>();
                        singleton.name = "[Singleton] " + typeof(T).ToString();

                        DontDestroyOnLoad(singleton);

                        Debug.Log("[Singleton] An instance of " + typeof(T) +
                            " is needed in the scene, so '" + singleton +
                            "' was created with DontDestroyOnLoad.");
                    }
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When Unity quits, it destroys objects in a random order.
    /// In principle, a Singleton is only destroyed when application quits.
    /// If any script calls Instance after it have been destroyed, 
    ///   it will create a buggy ghost object that will stay on the Editor scene
    ///   even after stopping playing the Application. Really bad!
    /// So, this was made to be sure we're not creating that buggy ghost object.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool applicationIsQuitting = false;
    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        applicationIsQuitting = true;
    }
}
```

Which is then used like:

```
public class MySingleton : Singleton<MySingleton>
{
     // Don't use the Awake method, Singleton uses it to initialize

     void Start() {
         Debug.Log("I'm a Singleton, access me through MySingleton.Instance");
     }
}
```

Comment: using `MySingleton.Instance` is actually more a misused side effect of the Singleton pattern and should be avoided whenever possible. The real purpose is making sure that there is only one instance of a class in the scene

Comment: Having multiple of the same class bloating the scene usually doesn't matter since you're only going to reference one of them(as long as the classes don't have passive behaviours). The MySingleton.Instance is a way of achieving access without instantiation in Unity, since we're forced to inherit from MonoBehaviour, which - like you said  - is not the definition of Singleton, but something we need to do in order to have purposefulfilling Singleton behaviour without adding dependency injection where you register classes as singleton to the IoC container, which would be the preferred way, I guess.

Comment: But yes, I believe the saying goes "friends don't let friends Singleton". I've yet to come up with an architecture in Unity for games that doesn't involve these kinds of classes. What're your experiences, do you successfully avoid this Instance pattern? Apart from zenject?

Comment: No it's not allways possible ;) I'm just saying the main purpose is having only one instance .. there are a lot of cases where multiple managers e.g. might get in each others way and either slow things down or fu** them up ^^ In terms of finding that instance most poeple stick to the singletons .. and so do I from time to time (if not using zenject - though .. in my point of view zenject also is somehow kind of a big singleton handling all references so ...). But as far as possible you should try to have clean references between components.

Comment: I only wnated to point out that the main purpose of singletons should not be the usage of `MySingleton.Instance`